# Probleem with substr in c++

Tags: c++

I made binary calculator. It works, but only when numbers doesnt start with 0. if yes, it shows this: [image: error picture]

How I should repair the program, please? (vysledek  means result)
Part of code with substr:

```
while(vysledek[0] == '0')
{
    vysledek = vysledek.substr(1, vysledek.length());
    w++;
}
int aa;
aa = p-w;
for(o; o < aa; o++)
{
    cout << vysledek[o];
}
```

Whole program:`

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        cout << "Zadejte dve binarni cisla:" << endl;
        string cislo1, cislo2;
        cin >> cislo1 >> cislo2;

    int c = 0;

    for (c; c < cislo1.length(); c++)
    {
        if ((cislo1[c] == '0') || (cislo1[c] == '1'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Nespravny vstup.";
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int d = 0;
    for (d; d < cislo2.length(); d++)
    {
        if ((cislo2[d] == '0') || (cislo2[d] == '1'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Nespravny vstup.";
            return 0;
        }
    }


    string stringS2 = "";
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < cislo1.length(); i++)
    {
    stringS2 += cislo1[cislo1.length()-1-i];
    }
    cislo1 = stringS2;

    string stringS3 = "";
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < cislo2.length(); i++)
    {
    stringS3 += cislo2[cislo2.length()-1-i];
    }
    cislo2 = stringS3;

    /*
    cout << cislo1 << endl;
    cout << cislo2 << endl;
    cout << cislo1.length() << endl;
    cout << cislo2.length() << endl;
    */

    int p;
    if (cislo1.length() > cislo2.length())
    {
         p = cislo1.length();
         int f = cislo2.length();
         for(f; f < cislo1.length(); f++)
         {
             cislo2[f] = '0';
         }
    }

    else
    {
        p = cislo2.length();
        int f = cislo1.length();
        for(f; f < cislo2.length(); f++)
        {
             cislo1[f] = '0';
        }
    }
    int e = 0;

    //cout << p << endl;

    string vysledek;
    int t;
    t = (p - 1);

    cislo1[p];
    cislo2[p];
   for(e; e < p; e++)
    {
        /*nasledujici podminky jsou pro pripad, kdy cisla maji odlisny pocet znaku
        if(cislo1[e] == NULL)
        {
            cislo1[e] == '0';
        }
        if(cislo2[e] == NULL)
        {
            cislo2[e] == '0';
        }*/

        if (cislo1[e] == '0' && cislo2[e] == '0')
            {

                if ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '1')|| ((cislo1[e-1] == '0' && cislo2[e-1] == '1')&& vysledek[t+1] == '0') || ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '0')&& vysledek[t+1] == '0') || ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '1')&& vysledek[t+1] == '1') )
                {
                    vysledek[t] = '1';
                }
                else
                {
                    vysledek[t] = '0';
                }
                //cout << vysledek[t] << endl;
                t--;

            }

        else if ((cislo1[e] == '1' && cislo2[e] == '0') || (cislo1[e] == '0' && cislo2[e] == '1') )
            {

                if ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '1') || ((cislo1[e-1] == '0' && cislo2[e-1] == '1')&& vysledek[t+1] == '0') || ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '0')&& vysledek[t+1] == '0') || ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '1')&& vysledek[t+1] == '1'))
                {
                    vysledek[t] = '0';
                }
                else
                {
                    vysledek[t] = '1';
                }
                // cout << vysledek[t] << endl;
                t--;
            }

        else if (cislo1[e] == '1' && cislo2[e] == '1')
            {

                if ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '1') || ((cislo1[e-1] == '0' && cislo2[e-1] == '1')&& vysledek[t+1] == '0') || ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '0')&& vysledek[t+1] == '0') || ((cislo1[e-1] == '1' && cislo2[e-1] == '1')&& vysledek[t+1] == '1'))
                {
                    vysledek[t] = '1';
                }
                else
                {
                    vysledek[t] = '0';
                }
                 //cout << vysledek[t] << endl;
                t--;
            }
    }
    cout << "Soucet: ";
    int u;
    u = (p - 1);
    if(((cislo1[u] == '0' && cislo2[u] == '1')&& vysledek[0] == '0') || ((cislo1[u] == '1' && cislo2[u] == '0')&& vysledek[0] == '0') || (cislo1[u] == '1' && cislo2[u] == '1') )
    cout << '1';


    int o = 0;
    int z;
    int w = 0;
    while(vysledek[0] == '0')
    {
        vysledek = vysledek.substr(1, vysledek.length());
        w++;
    }
    int aa;
    aa = p-w;
    for(o; o < aa; o++)
    {
        cout << vysledek[o];
    }





    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Is it really easier to take a picture of the command prompt window, post it to imgur, and link to it here than it would be to just copy-and-paste the text from it?

Comment: @DanKorn There doesnt work ctrl + c

Comment: @Tux -- *How I should repair the program* -- Learning how to "repair programs" is part of learning how to be a programmer.  It isn't just write a program, and if it doesn't work correctly, post on SO waiting for an answer.  Please use or learn to use the debugger to step through your code.

Comment: You don't use Ctrl-C to copy from a Command Prompt (at least not before Windows 10).  That doesn't mean it's impossible to copy text though.  You have to use the context menu that comes up with you right-click the title bar.  It's really not that hard to Google to find out how to do it: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @DanKorn It works thanks

Answer (score 1):

`string vysledek;` creates an empty string. It is never given any other size.

All following uses of `vysledek[t]` and `vysledek.substr` are all out of range.

Comment: Bo Persson OK but why program works for numbers which start with 1?

Comment: It probably doesn't, because then  `cislo1[e-1]` will be out of range when `e` is zero. Note that one possible outcome of undefined behavior in a program is "seems to work".